# If Else w/ Selected Radio Options

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is becoming more difficult than I had expected. I'm trying to write an if/else statement using jquery selectors.. I'd like to append a message depending on which radio is clicked. My logic works, but I cannot get messages to output when a certain radio button is clicked. I can easily print both results at the same time, but cannot figure out how to print separate responses depending on the radio chosen.

Here is my function:

```
function imageCounter() {

  var ballCount = 0;
  var truckCount = 0;

  // find images with ball in image src
  $('img[src*=ball]').each(function() {  
    if($(this).attr('src')) {  
      ballCount+=1;
    }     
  });

  // find images with truck in image src
  $('img[src*=truck]').each(function() { 
    if($(this).attr('src')) {
      truckCount+=1;
    }
  });

  if($(':radio[name="truckImages"]:checked')) {
    $('#radioButtons').append("There are " + truckCount + " truck images.");
  } else {
    $('#radioButtons').append("There are " + ballCount + " ball images.");
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="radioButtons">
  <input type="radio" value="truckImages" name="truckImages" id="truckImages">Fire Trucks
  <input type="radio" value="ballImages" name="ballImages" id="ballImages">
  <input type="button" value="Count the Images" onclick="imageCounter()">
</div>
```

Comment: `if($(':radio[name="truckImages"]:checked'))` will always be true because the return value of the `$()` function is an object *even if no element matched*. Also, what do you think `if($(this).attr('src'))` does? (Hint: it will always be true because you know the `src` will be a non-empty string.)

Comment: you should put the same name for the radio buttons first so it would be a unique radio chosen

Comment: The if($(this).attr('src')) is the only way I could get my counter to work for specific images :/  Basically used it to validate that attributes with src are being counted.

Comment: Okay. I was wrong, Went back and removed the .attr. Was able to complete this using just the (this). 
Now I'm back to the problem of these printing at the same time.. sigh.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem would be that $.fn would return an array of elements that match the query. If there's not any element match, if would return an empty array. In JavaScript, `!![]` would return `true`. Here, you should use `.length`

```
  if($(':radio[name="truckImages"]:checked').length) {
    $('#radioButtons').append("There are " + truckCount + " truck images.");
  } else {
    $('#radioButtons').append("There are " + ballCount + " ball images.");
  }
```

or

```
  if($(':radio[name="truckImages"]').is(':checked')) {
    $('#radioButtons').append("There are " + truckCount + " truck images.");
  } else {
    $('#radioButtons').append("There are " + ballCount + " ball images.");
  }
```

Actually, I don't think you need to call the each function of the $('img').

```
function imageCount() {
  var type = $(':radio:checked')).attr('name').replace(/Images$/, '');
  var count = $('img[src*=' + type + ']').length;
  $('#radioButtons').after("There are " + count + " " + type + " images.");
}
```